# Need to run a query present in excel cell connect to Athena and show in another worksheet

Tags: excel, odbc, amazon-athena

I have a complex excel formula which generate a sql query in a excel cell.
I want to connect Athena from Excel and run the query and get the output saved in the another sheet in same excel workbook.
How to pass the value of a cell and run it.

as an example
-- in sheet 1 I have cell B3 where some formula generate the query "Select a, b from table abc"
-- in Sheet . connect ODBC to Athena database
-- While connecting pass the "B3" cell value and capture the out put in Sheet 2

Next time if I change some parameter which changes the SQL query in B3 , I simply refresh the query and the new output will be captured there.

Please help

I tried to pass the cell value in SQL statement while connecting to Athena via ODBC. That didn't work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.